# Samsung Galaxy S4 stuck on Samsung logo after booting from Odin

Tags: rom-flashing, odin

After booting from Odin, I can't turn on the screen. It gets stuck on Samsung Galaxy S4 logo. I tried to do a factory reset. It says completed, but then it has a `no command` error under the Android logo.

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The good new is your phone is not bricked, so yes, you can still fix it.

Just enter download mode again and flash with odin one more time.

To enter download mode you have to:

1. Power off your phone
2. Press and hold <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons at the same time.
3. Press <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> button when warning prompt.

Answer (score 0):

After flashing please wipe data cache and dalvic cache.